# Erro na função de forçar download por php

Tags: php

Ola estou com o código abaixo de forçar e renomear arquivos de media em mp4 via download de URL remota com tudo o download esta vindo corrompido pois não esta efetuando o download devidamente. Como posso concertar isso pois o arquivo ao efetuar o download esta ficando com 2kbs de tamanho.

```
$file = 'http://thumb.mais.uol.com.br/15328248.mp4';
$nome = 'novoNome.mp4';
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . ($nome) . '";'); 
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen(file_get_contents($file)));
readfile($file);
```

Comment: cara, eu testei seu código e o download funcionou normalmente, não pode ser algo em sua rede que corrompeu o download? faz o teste com arquivos menores ou de outros tipos... neste [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php) diz para colocar ob_clean(); flush(); antes do readfile, veja se muda algo pra vc....

Comment: Aqui só funcionou com arquivos pequenos necessito que funcione com arquivos grandes no max ate 300mbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se os atributos:

memory_limit, 
post_max_size,
upload_max_filesize, 
max_execution_time

Estão com os valores que você deseja no php.ini

Comment: ai que ta coloquei tudo a 300 mb e mesmo assim ainda não pega o tamanho maximo do arquivo deixando ele corrompido com 2kbs. E no caso eu estou pegando URL remota não estou efetuando o upload deste arquivo pro meu servidor só necessito que ele pegue o tamanho certo e mude o nome do arquivo direto pela header.

Comment: Você modificou o memory_limit para quanto? Geralmente esse tipo de erro ocorre porque o servidor consome mais que 300 MB quando é solicitado um download de algo de 300 MB. Dai depende de quanto você pode aumentar no seu servidor. Mas, tinha casos que eu tinha que setar 1024 MB ou 2048 para conseguir passar grandes downloads para o usuário. (as vezes eu só setava esses valores na página PHP que utilizava o download).
Ou então modificava o PHP ini, reiniciava o APACHE e ia tranquilo.

Comment: Os arquivos não chegam nem a 200mb e memory_limit coloquei a 300mb.

Comment: Mas, como te disse, ele sempre consome mais que o tamanho do arquivo.  E, no caso, eu sempre modificava pelo menos os 3 parametros (upload max filesize, post max size e o memory limit). Tenta colocar um tamanho maior e veja se vai.